# How to reproduce the event of closing the keyboard area of iPhone message app?

Tags: ios, flutter, scrollview

I try to replicate iPhone's Message app behavior when we scroll down in chat view.

More specifically, when the keyboard is opened, I would like to reproduce the event of closing the keyboard area when we slide the finger to the bottom of the screen beyond a threshold or when we get past the Textfield of writing a message

I would like to get pointer coordinates when I am scrolling my ScrollView. I tried with ScrollController and ScrollNotification; I can get scroll offset but not the point coordinates in screen or viewport. I tried with GestureDectetor on my ScrollView but this ScrollView catches first events. So GestureDetector stays silent.

Am I on a good path or is there any better approaches I  can try or is it simply not possible with Flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

The is a 'keyboardDismissMode`property on the native`UITableView`. Check if there is an equivalent property in flutter scrollview.